# UITableView row delete crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

I have a Core Data based table view that has a simple delete method. It is straightforward code that can be found in countless tutorials, however, it crashes the app with the following message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

The delete method is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // get garden to delete, delete it through Core Data


        Garden *gardenToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Garden name: %@", gardenToDelete.gardenName);

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:gardenToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        }
}
```

I have spent hours rearranging the code, removing the `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` calls, checking other solutions. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is self.fetchedResultsController and self.managedObjectContext?

Comment: The view's core data stack objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to delete the object from your `NSFetchedResultsController`, the fetched results controller will then update the table view assuming you've implemented the delegate methods as described in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008228-CH1-SW136). You shouldn't touch the table view rows, the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` does all of that.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

      // deleting cell from fetched results contoller

      Garden *gardenToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      NSLog(@"Garden name: %@", gardenToDelete.gardenName); 
      [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:gardenToDelete];
      [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, the object is deleted from core data, but the row remains intact. If you tap the row the app crashes (because there is no data behind the row)

Comment: @Andrew see the docs link I posted in my answer, you need to set a [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW12) on `self.fetchedResultsController`, and implement the delegate methods for updates

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement these methods:

```
 - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

// my comment: mapIndexPathFromFetchResultsController function, I just use to get indexPath. You can remove it 
indexPath = [self mapIndexPathFromFetchResultsController:indexPath];
newIndexPath = [self mapIndexPathFromFetchResultsController:newIndexPath];

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
    {
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell != nil)
        {
            // my comment: just use the same with cellForRowAtIndexPath
            // - (void)syncViewConfigureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
            // cell.textLabel.text = @""; etc. }
            [self syncViewConfigureCell:cell];
        }
        break;
    }

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }
}
    }


    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
    }


    - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
[self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

Comment: What is the `mapIndexPathFromFetchResultsController:` method? What is the `syncViewConfigureCell:` method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` with a return value with `NSFetchedResultsController`? After you do save, `self.fetchedResultsController` will refresh, but make sure all of the dataSource of tableView return value is depended on `self.fetchedResultsController`.